# Pruned Dynamic Programming

Tags: dynamic-programming, pruning

Currently, I'm working a string alignment comparison. I'm confused on how to optimize DP by pruning.

DP can be represented as a matrix/table. The start point is (0, 0). For example, element at (3, 4) is pruned and its value marked as -1 or null. But when I compute location (4, 4), (3, 5) and (4, 5), I still need a if-statement to check whether the value of (3, 4) is invalid(pruned) or valid(not pruned). Can this implementation save time because pruning function brings extra running time???

Comment: Pruning is usually very important in order to save _memory_ and not time. For example - look into [SMA*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMA*)

Comment: You should try to fill only the valid parts of the table (for example using DFS/BFS)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum So I need use a tree instead of a 2D array?

Comment: @NiklasB. So I need a tree instead of a 2D array?

Comment: @happy: No, you probably need a sparse table (only store the valid entries)

Comment: @NiklasB.thanks a lot.  i'll try it